Nested transfinite sequence of closed sets in second countable spaces
If a space with countable basis has a well ordered (transfinite) sequence of nested closed sets, then it contains at most a countable number of distinct elements.
This is to be found in p. 59 of K.S. Sibirsky, Introduction to topological dynamics, Noordhoff Int. Publ. 1975. He refers to "Baire-Hausdorff theorem" in p. 274, P.S Aleksandrov, Introduction to the general theory of sets and functions, 1948 (Russian).
How can I prove this? Or, is there any other reference in english with proof?

Let $X$ be a second countable space and let $(F_\alpha)_{\alpha<\xi}$ be a transfinite sequence of closed sets in $X$ such that $\alpha<\beta\implies F_\beta\subsetneq F_\alpha$. We want to show that $\xi$ is a countable ordinal.
Let $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ enumerate a countable basis of $X$ and to each closed subset $F$ of $X$ associate the set $B(F)=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid F\cap U_n\neq\varnothing\}$. It is easy to check that $F\mapsto B(F)$ is an injection, and that $G\subsetneq F\implies B(G)\subsetneq B(F)$. In other words from any strictly decreasing transfinite sequence of closed sets in $X$, we get a strictly decreasing transfinite sequence of subsets of $\mathbb N$, and the latter must be countable.

where do we use that the sets are closed or the well ordering in the proof?

@Allotrios we use that the sets are closed to show that $F\mapsto B(F)$ is injective (because $X\setminus F$ is the union of the open sets whose index in the enumeration is not in $B(F)$). We use the well ordering to argue that the sequence of subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable, there are uncountable $\subseteq$-chains in $P(\mathbb N)$, but no well-ordered ones
